# How can i do a date picker only month and year whith valueChangeHandler by month?

Tags: java, gwt, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker but I only need the month and year without the days, 
and the `valueChangeHandler` uses the day but I want it to use the month selected

I'm using:

```
 import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil;
 import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox;
 import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarView;
 import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarModel;
 import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DefaultCalendarView;

        dateBox.getDatePicker().addValueChangeHandler(valueChangeHandler);
        dateBox.getDatePicker().setYearArrowsVisible(true);
        dateBox.getDatePicker().setYearAndMonthDropdownVisible(true);


    private ValueChangeHandler<Date> valueChangeHandler = new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() 
    {

        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) 
        {
            dateBox.setValue(event.getValue());
            checkConstraints();
        }
    };
```